# I am using OLEDB is only reading the first 11 rows of the excel sheet

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbcommand, oledbdatareader

I am having an issue with a data reader object that seems to only be reading the first 11 rows from an excel spreadsheet.  I have tried updating the OLEDB driver from JET to ACE and have also tried adding a .HasRows clause to my .Read() loop.  Nothing seems to work.  Same result every time.

This Arraylist populates an object created to hold all of the data from the excel file

```
public ArrayList LoadCensusFromExcelFile( string fPath)
{
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection() ;
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + `
`fPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";" ;
try
{
conn.Open() ;
}
        catch (OleDbException ex)   
        {   
            conn.Close();   
            conn.Dispose();   
            throw (ex);   
        } 
            catch( System.Exception openFailed )
        {
            _errorMessage = "Could not open workbook: " + openFailed.ToString() ;
            Log.LogMessage(openFailed,"Census Excel Upload Failed {0}","Connect String: " + conn.ConnectionString + "Message: " + openFailed.ToString());
            return null ;
        }
            ArrayList census = new ArrayList() ;

        try
        {
            census = _loadCensus(conn) ;
        }
        catch( System.Exception e )
        {
            _errorMessage = "Uncaught CensusImport._loadCensus() exception: " + e.ToString() ;
            Log.LogMessage(e,"Census Excel Upload Failed {0}",e.ToString());
            return null ;
        }
```

//this is the declaration of the reader object and the query of the excel sheet

```
    private ArrayList _loadCensus( OleDbConnection conn )
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader rdr = null ;

        try
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand( "select * from Census", conn ) ;
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader() ;
        }
        catch ( System.Exception e )
        {
            _errorMessage = "Could not execute select statement: " + e.ToString() ;
            Log.LogMessage(e,"Census Excel Upload Failed {0}",e.ToString());
            return null ;
        }

        return _loadCensusData( rdr ) ;
    }
```

Finally, this ArrayList populates all of the data from the excel sheet.  it loops though until it gets to the 11th row and the starts returning NULL values.

rdr2String is a custom method that converts all of the indexed values in the reader object into strings.

```
private ArrayList _loadCensusData( OleDbDataReader rdr )
    {

        ArrayList censusList = new ArrayList() ;
        CensusVO census ;

        string FirstName ;
        string LastName ;
        string[] BirthDate = new string[2];
        string AppAge ;
        string AppGender ;

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            census = new CensusVO() ;

            FirstName       = rdr2String(rdr,0,50) ;
            LastName        = rdr2String(rdr,1,50) ;
            BirthDate[0]    = rdr2String(rdr,2,30) ;
            AppAge          = rdr2String(rdr,3,30) ;
            AppGender       = rdr2String(rdr,4,1) ;


            censusList.Add(census);
           }

            return censusList ;
}
```

Comment: I'd hate for you to have to rewrite this, but you shouldn't use OLE to read Excel files. Take a look at [EP Plus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for a much easier way to deal with reading and writing spreadsheets. If you try to run this in a web scenario, the fact that Office is not built to be run on a server will cause you far too many headaches.

Comment: Not sure I agree. It is not always possible to use 3rd party tools and you certainly can't always install Office to use Interop. In those cases OLEDB is the best and only solution.

Comment: I agree with @Ciarán.  I am trying not to use any third party tools at all.  Hence why I wrote it using OLEDB.

Comment: Your "Select * From Census" leads me to think this is a named range in the spreadsheet rather than a work sheet. Work sheet names usually end in $. Use the GetSchema("Tables") method of you connection to get the available table names and see if this is the case.